# Is there a way to view edits that were made to my answers?

Tags: support, editing

I gave an answer to a question, and then I got a notification that it was edited. I want to see what the edit was, in order to see how to better my answers, my spelling and grammar, but unlike with questions, when I enter edit mode, it doesn't show me the previous versions, so I can't compare between them.

Is there a way to see previous versions of my answers, or the diffs between my answer and the edit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see the revision history of a question or answer, simply click where it says, for example, "Edited 3 hours ago".

That will take you to the revision history, where you can see what changes were made.

---

This line was added in an edit.

Comment: I have edited this post so you can have an example.